# Creating a geofence with html5 geolocation api

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation, geofencing

I'm looking at using the HTML5 geolocation API to check to see if a user is in a particular location. However, I would like to give some lenience on this so I was hoping I could specify a central **lat** and **lng**, and then set a radius around that, so that as long as they were within that range the site would work.

I was wondering if there is any JS formula I can use to check if a user falls within this radius.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These guys are getting to the Solution for this:

http://www.w3.org/TR/geofencing/

Regards,
George

Comment: Any updates on this?
Is there any browser that supports it?